# Using one array to index another in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to learn Ruby, and I'm wondering how an array can be used to index another array, for example,

in Perl this is: `my @x = @y[@ro]`, where all three variables are just generic arrays.

how can I accomplish the same thing in Ruby?

Comment: What do you mean by "Using one array to index another"? What are the semantics you want to achieve?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I showed in the code what I want to achieve. I can do this in perl and python, but I don't know how to accomplish `my @x = @y[@ro]` in Ruby

Comment: Your code doesn't show the semantics of what you want to achieve. What is `@y`? What is `@ro`? Can you show the definition of the `my` method?

Comment: `@y` `@ro` are generic arrays, `my` is just a declaration, I thought that this would be clear as this is simple Perl code.  This is part of a larger project to translate http://rosettacode.org/wiki/P-value_correction#Perl into Ruby, which I'm using for tutorial purposes

Comment: What does the Perl code do? What is its result? What are its side-effects? What are the semantics of what you want to achieve? Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Comment: Note that all languages have subtle differences, so without a *precise* specification of which parts of the Perl behavior you want to copy and which are irrelevant, the answer is pretty much always going to be "there is no such thing". Also, if you don't explain what you want to achieve, then your question can only be answered by experts of Perl *and* Ruby, whereas if you explain it, then it can be answered by any Ruby programmer, even those who don't know Perl.

Comment: @JörgWMittag please see the accepted answer by "mu is too short", he got my question 100% :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember my Perl correctly, given:

```
my @ro = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
my @y  = (1, 3);
```

Then `@ro[@y]` would be `('b', 'd')` so the notation is just a short form for extracting all the elements of the array `@ro` at the indexes in `@y`.

In Ruby, I'd use [`Array#values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-values_at) and a splat thusly:

```
ro = %w[a b c d e]
y  = [1, 3]
x  = ro.values_at(*y)
```

The `*y` splat unwraps the array and gives you its elements so `ro.values_at(*y)` is equivalent to `ro.values_at(1, 3)` in this case.

Comment: ...or `y.map { |i| ro[i] }`.